# File Not Found Exception when reading files Xamarin IOS MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need confirmation if this is an actual bug or if I'm doing it wrong.

Basically I am using this code to load an xml file:

```
string xmlStr = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("AppSetting/ServiceEndpoints.xml");
```

which works in IPhoneSimulator but when deployed to an actual device, it gives me a `File Not Found Exception`.

I already set the file both as a Content and a Bundle Resource but still on both settings I get the same exception.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: check your casing - the simulator is NOT case sensitive, while an actual device IS

Comment: i already did and the casings are good ...

Answer (score 0):

OK for anyone who will get into the same situation, apparently looks like the guide from Xamarin documentation about using the function does not work on the device itself probably either the guide has not been updated yet or ios 10.2 has a new security feature about the File System, i managed to make it work by using this procedure.

string dir = NSBundle.MainBundle.ResourcePath;

string xmlStr = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(dir + "/ServiceEndpoints.xml");